# Why the TabbedPane lose his background color when applying setLookAndFeel?

Tags: java, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

Can't understand why when applying setLookAndFeel for my Java application, the tabbedPane lose the background that I set before.

Before applying setLookAndFeel:

[image]

After applying setLookAndFeel:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class CoocHelpPanel {

    
    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CoocHelpPanel window = new CoocHelpPanel();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public CoocHelpPanel() {
        initialize();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("TEST TAB COLOR");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(10, 10, 965, 855);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("TAB 1 - AAAA", null, panel, null);
        tabbedPane.setBackgroundAt(0, Color.red);
        panel.setLayout(null);
    
                
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("TAB 2 - BBBB", null, panel_1, null);
        tabbedPane.setBackgroundAt(1, Color.red);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the javadoc of setBackgroundAt, you'll see:
**It is up to the look and feel to honor this property, some may choose to ignore it.**
WindowsLookAndFeel does not honor, the default one (metal?) does. That's why.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so is there a way to change the background when lookAndFeel is appliyed?

Comment: Select a look&feel that honors that property, Or maybe you'll succeed in changing uidefauts.